# Deforming through infinity

Tags: complex-analysis, asymptotics, riemann-surfaces

Say that I have an entire function $f$ on $\mathbb{C}_\infty$. I was thinking the following. If say the integral $$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} f dz=k$$
for some number $k$, does this mean that all integrals through infinity exist? I thought this is obvious by Cauchy's theorem applied on the Riemann sphere, however, I am not quite sure.  The issue is that if I would go by this analogy, since $f$ is entire, I should have $\int f =0$ because of analiticty of the "interior" (?). I am not sure quite sure what is going on. This is motivated from thinking about asymptotic expansions through contour integrals and how, at least my course, assumes the above fact.

**Question:** If an entire function $f$ on $\mathbb{C}_\infty$has $$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} f dz=k$$
for some number $k$, what can we say about all integrals along paths going through infinity (as viwed on the riemann sphere)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} e^{-z^{2}} dz$ exists but the integral over the imaginary axis of this function does not.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the answer. Could you elaborate on what is going on behind the scenes? I understand that your example shows that the claim is not true however whats going on a deeper level? Is it that deformation doesn't work because there are issues with defining an interior when we are going through infinity or something else is going on?

Comment: Right. It is not possible to construct  closed contours, apply Cauchy's Theorem and take limits to equate the integrals over the two axes when $\infty$ is involved.  @MathsWizzard

Comment: Thank you very much. This answers my question.